# When Declaring A Function For Tap Gestures & Notifications Are Parameters/Arguments Necessary?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, parameter-passing, uitapgesturerecognizer

I know how tap gestures and notifications work so that's not the question.

What I notice is I've seen some people use a parameter/argument for a tap gesture function or a notification function:

```
override viewDidLoad(){
   super.viewDidLoad()


   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notifyMe), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: notificationKey), object: nil)

   let gesture = UITapGesture(target: self, action: #selector(tapMe))
   view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}


@objc func tapMe(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
   // do something
}

@objc func notifyMe(_ notification: Notification){
   // do something
}
```

However I've used the functions both with and without a parameter/argument and they work fine:

```
@objc func tapMe(){
   // do something
}

@objc func notifyMe(){
   // do something
}
```

**What's the purpose of using the parameters/arguments if they work without them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose is to be able to identify and distinguish the `sender` / the `object` and in case of the notication to be able to get additional information / data from the `userInfo` dictionary.

Comment: ahhhhhhh, that actually makes sense because 1 time I was using the userInfo dict without the function params and the function was't running. I couldn't figure out what the problem was. Now this answers the question. Basically as long as the userInfo dict isn't being used it's fine. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, the parameters are optional. This is because when a selector is performed, the objective-C runtime does not care whether the selector has the correct number of arguments or whatever. It just passes a bunch of objects to the selector. If the selector has matching parameters, then the parameters will have the corresponding values of the objects passed. If it does not, the objects will just get thrown away. This is also why you can declare `IBAction`s with a parameter of a specific `UIControl` type, `AnyObject`, or no parameter at all.

When the selector is performed, the additional objects that it is performed with is obviously not always useless. If you have multiple gestures recognisers or `UIButton`s connected to one single method. Then it is useful to know who is the `sender`. For notifications, the parameter usually contains some information about the notification, which might be useful.